# What is the difference between Dataset.from_tensors and Dataset.from_tensor_slices?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have a dataset represented as a NumPy matrix of shape `(num_features, num_examples)` and I wish to convert it to TensorFlow type `tf.Dataset`.

I am struggling trying to understand the difference between these two methods: `Dataset.from_tensors` and `Dataset.from_tensor_slices`. What is the right one and why?

TensorFlow documentation ([link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset)) says that both method accept a nested structure of tensor although when using `from_tensor_slices` the tensor should have same size in the 0-th dimension.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

`from_tensors` combines the input and returns a dataset with a single element:

```
>>> t = tf.constant([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
>>> ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(t)
>>> [x for x in ds]
[<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 2), dtype=int32, numpy=
 array([[1, 2],
        [3, 4]], dtype=int32)>]
```

`from_tensor_slices` creates a dataset with a separate element for each row of the input tensor:

```
>>> t = tf.constant([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
>>> ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(t)
>>> [x for x in ds]
[<tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([1, 2], dtype=int32)>,
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([3, 4], dtype=int32)>]
```

Comment: @MathewScarpino: can you elaborate more on when to use when?

Comment: I think the source of confusion (at least for it was), is the name. Since the from_tensor_slices creates slices from the original data...the ideal name should have been "to_tensor_slices" - Because you are taking your data and create tensor slices out of it. Once you think along those lines all documentation from TF2 became very clear for me !

Comment: A key piece of info for me that was absent from the docs was that multiple tensors are passed to these methods as a tuple, e.g. `from_tensors((t1,t2,t3,))`. With that knowledge, `from_tensors` makes a dataset where each input tensor is like a *row* of your dataset, and `from_tensor_slices` makes a dataset where each input tensor is *column* of your data; so in the latter case all tensors must be the same length, and the elements (rows) of the resulting dataset are tuples with one element from each column.

Answer (score 18):

1) Main difference between the two is that nested elements in [`from_tensor_slices`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_tensor_slices) must have the same dimension in 0th rank:

```
# exception: ValueError: Dimensions 10 and 9 are not compatible
dataset1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
    (tf.random_uniform([10, 4]), tf.random_uniform([9])))
# OK, first dimension is same
dataset2 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(
    (tf.random_uniform([10, 4]), tf.random_uniform([10])))
```

2) The second difference, explained [here](http://mlexplore.org/2018/01/25/tensorflow-dataset-api-exploration-part-1/), is when the input to a tf.Dataset is a list. For example:

```
dataset1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
    [tf.random_uniform([2, 3]), tf.random_uniform([2, 3])])

dataset2 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(
    [tf.random_uniform([2, 3]), tf.random_uniform([2, 3])])

print(dataset1) # shapes: (2, 3)
print(dataset2) # shapes: (2, 2, 3)
```

In the above, `from_tensors` creates a 3D tensor while `from_tensor_slices` merge the input tensor. This can be handy if you have different sources of different image channels and want to concatenate them into a one RGB image tensor.

3) A mentioned in the previous answer, `from_tensors` convert the input tensor into one big tensor:

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.enable_eager_execution()

dataset1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
    (tf.random_uniform([4, 2]), tf.random_uniform([4])))

dataset2 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(
    (tf.random_uniform([4, 2]), tf.random_uniform([4])))

for i, item in enumerate(dataset1):
    print('element: ' + str(i + 1), item[0], item[1])

print(30*'-')

for i, item in enumerate(dataset2):
    print('element: ' + str(i + 1), item[0], item[1])
```

output:

```
element: 1 tf.Tensor(... shapes: ((2,), ()))
element: 2 tf.Tensor(... shapes: ((2,), ()))
element: 3 tf.Tensor(... shapes: ((2,), ()))
element: 4 tf.Tensor(... shapes: ((2,), ()))
-------------------------
element: 1 tf.Tensor(... shapes: ((4, 2), (4,)))
```

Comment: PS: It should be tf.random.uniform not tf.random_uniform

Comment: how can one convert one type to another ? I can see some tf functions return error depending what type is used

Answer (score 14):

Try this :

```
import tensorflow as tf  # 1.13.1
tf.enable_eager_execution()

t1 = tf.constant([[11, 22], [33, 44], [55, 66]])

print("\n=========     from_tensors     ===========")
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(t1)
print(ds.output_types, end=' : ')
print(ds.output_shapes)
for e in ds:
    print (e)

print("\n=========   from_tensor_slices    ===========")
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(t1)
print(ds.output_types, end=' : ')
print(ds.output_shapes)
for e in ds:
    print (e)
```

output :

```
=========      from_tensors    ===========
<dtype: 'int32'> : (3, 2)
tf.Tensor(
[[11 22]
 [33 44]
 [55 66]], shape=(3, 2), dtype=int32)

=========   from_tensor_slices      ===========
<dtype: 'int32'> : (2,)
tf.Tensor([11 22], shape=(2,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([33 44], shape=(2,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([55 66], shape=(2,), dtype=int32)
```

The output is pretty much self-explanatory but as you can see, from_tensor_slices() slices the output of (what would be the output of) from_tensors() on its first dimension. You can also try with :

```
t1 = tf.constant([[[11, 22], [33, 44], [55, 66]],
                  [[110, 220], [330, 440], [550, 660]]])
```

Comment: with tf 2 i get: AttributeError: 'TensorDataset' object has no attribute 'output_types'

Answer (score 13):

I think @MatthewScarpino clearly explained the differences between these two methods.

Here I try to describe the typical usage of these two methods:

- `from_tensors` can be used to construct a larger dataset from several small datasets, i.e., the size (length) of the dataset becomes larger;
- while `from_tensor_slices` can be used to combine different elements into one dataset, e.g., combine features and labels into one dataset (that's also why the 1st dimension of the tensors should be the same). That is, the dataset becomes "wider".

Answer (score 5):

## In simple:

> from_tensors()

returns: **single element,**
type: **TensorDataset**

> from_tensor_slices()

returns: **multiple elements** of input length,
type: **TensorSliceDataset**

## Explanation:

##### from_tensors()

> With 1-D input

```
import tensorflow as tf
dataset_ft = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors([1, 2, 3])
type(dataset_ft)

>>> tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.TensorDataset
```

Now, if we loop through this Dataset we will only get one object:

```
for _ in dataset_ft:
    print(_)  

>>> tf.Tensor([1 2 3], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
```

What if we provide 2-D or more dimensional input?

> With 2-D input

```
import tensorflow as tf
dataset_ft = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
type(dataset_ft)

>>> tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.TensorDataset
```

Now, if we loop through this Dataset we will still get only one object:

```
for _ in dataset_ft:
    print(_)

>>> tf.Tensor(
>>> [[1 2 3]
>>> [4 5 6]], shape=(2, 3), dtype=int32)
```

As you see that the shape or produced tensor is as of input. There is no change in the shape.

##### from_tensor_slices()

It removes the first dimension and use it as a dataset dimension.

> With 1-D input

```
import tensorflow as tf
dataset_fts = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([1, 2, 3])
type(dataset_fts)

>>> tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.TensorSliceDataset
```

Now, if we loop through this Dataset we will have multiple objects:

```
for _ in dataset_fts:
    print(_)

>>> tf.Tensor(1, shape=(), dtype=int32)
>>> tf.Tensor(2, shape=(), dtype=int32)
>>> tf.Tensor(3, shape=(), dtype=int32)
```

What if we provide 2-D or more dimensional input?

> With 2-D input

```
import tensorflow as tf
dataset_fts = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
type(dataset_fts)

>>> tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops.TensorSliceDataset
```

If we loop through this 2-D dataset we will have two 1-D elements:

```
for _ in dataset_fts:
    print(_)

>>> tf.Tensor([1 2 3], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
>>> tf.Tensor([4 5 6], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
```

That's the simplest I can explain. To get a better understanding I would suggest you run both these functions with different inputs and see the shape of returned elements.