# Training using tf.Dataset in TensorFlow 2.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow

I'm having difficulty training my TensorFlow model using a `tf.Dataset` rather than, say, a `pd.DataFrame` (which works fine).

I have created a dummy example below that I would expect to work given what I have read online/on the [TensorFlow website](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data).

```py
!pip install tensorflow==2.0.0 > /dev/null

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

features, target = np.random.rand(100, 30), np.random.randint(0, 2, 100)
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features, target))

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(30, activation='relu', input_shape=(30,)),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),

    tf.keras.layers.Dense(30, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),

    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss='binary_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

model.fit(
    dataset, 
    epochs=10,
)
```

which returns the following error message

```
...

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_input to have shape (30,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

Is there anything obviously wrong in the above? Why is TensorFlow grabbing an input with shape `(1,)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors` instead `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices`

The difference explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55370549/10418812