# Trying to create a MLP for binary classification but gets an input shape error

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, mlp

I'm trying to create MLP for binary classification using Heart Attack Analysis and Prediction dataset from kaggle (https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/rashikrahmanpritom/heart-attack-analysis-prediction-dataset) but when i try to fit the model i get this error in 1st epoch

```
ValueError: in user code: File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1284, in train_function * return step_function(self, iterator) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1268, in step_function ** outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,)) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1249, in run_step ** outputs = model.train_step(data) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1050, in train_step y_pred = self(x, training=True) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py", line 253, in assert_input_compatibility raise ValueError(

ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'sequential_1' (type Sequential).

Input 0 of layer "dense_3" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1.

Full shape received: (13,)

Call arguments received by layer 'sequential_1' (type Sequential):

• inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(13,), dtype=float64)

• training=True

• mask=None
```

my input shapes are (227, 13) , (227,) , (76, 13) , (76,) for X_train, y_train, X_test and y_test respectively. so i'm not sure where this error is coming from. Why is this happening?

here's my code:

```
df=pd.read_csv(csv_file_path)

X=df.drop(columns=\['output'\])

y=df\['output'\]

df=pd.read_csv(csv_file_path)

X=df.drop(columns=\['output'\])

y=df\['output'\]
# convert dataframes to tensorflow data sets
train_dataset=tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train.values\[1:\], y_train.values\[1:\]))
test_dataset=tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_test.values\[1:\], y_test.values\[1:\]))

model=tf.keras.Sequential(\[
tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=(None, X_train.shape\[1\],)),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
\])

model.compile(
optimizer='adam',
loss='binary_crossentropy',
metrics=\['accuracy'\]
)

model.compile(
optimizer='adam',
loss='binary_crossentropy',
metrics=\['accuracy'\]
)

history=model.fit(
train_dataset,
epochs=10,
validation_data=test_dataset
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be related with the call to `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices()`:

```py
train_dataset=tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train.values[1:], y_train.values[1:]))
test_dataset=tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_test.values[1:], y_test.values[1:]))
```

Essentially, `from_tensor_slices()` takes the `(227, 13)` tensor (perhaps `(226, 13)` if you use `X[1:]`) and creates a dataset with 227 elements, each of shape `(13,)`, i.e. without the batch dimension. To make the code work, you can use [`Dataset.batch()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#:%7E:text=is%20not%20enabled.-,batch,-View%20source) to define the batch size:

```py
train_dataset=tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train.values[1:], y_train.values[1:]))
test_dataset=tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_test.values[1:], y_test.values[1:]))

train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(16)  # or some other batch size
test_dataset = test_dataset.batch(4)  # can use different batch size for train & test
```

Perhaps [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49579684/what-is-the-difference-between-dataset-from-tensors-and-dataset-from-tensor-slic) is helpful in understanding the `from_tensor_slices` function. And this [part of TF docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data#:%7E:text=Batching%20dataset%20elements) can be helpful in using the `tf.data` pipeline for batching.